# Why does my component have a height of 0?

Tags: css, blazor-server-side, azure-maps, azuremapscontrol

I am using the [AzureMapControl](https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/AzureMapsControl.Components) `<AzureMap>` component in a Blazor server-side web app. If I have it as the sole content of my Index.razor page, it displays fine. (This was in a small sample app I wrote).

But when I move it to my application I want to use it in, which has a lot of stuff in the MainLayout.razor, it has a height of 0. I finally tried to force a height doing the following:

```
<div style="width: 600px; height: 600px;">
<AzureMap Id="map"
          CameraOptions="new CameraOptions { Zoom = 12 }"
          Controls="new Control[]
{
    new ZoomControl(new ZoomControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.TopLeft),
    new CompassControl(new CompassControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.BottomLeft),
    new StyleControl(new StyleControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto, MapStyles = MapStyle.All() }, ControlPosition.BottomRight)
}"
          StyleOptions="new StyleOptions { ShowLogo = false }"
          EventActivationFlags="MapEventActivationFlags.None().Enable(MapEventType.Ready)"
          OnReady="OnMapReadyAsync" />
</div>
```

But it's still a height of 0:
[image]

What can cause this and how do I get it to have a height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is a really horrible hack. (And I'll have to figure out what values to set based on the browser window size.) But it works.

Add the following style:

```
<style>
    #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 600px;
    }
</style>

<AzureMap Id="map"
          CameraOptions="new CameraOptions { Zoom = 12 }"
          Controls="new Control[]
                {
                    new ZoomControl(new ZoomControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.TopLeft),
                    new CompassControl(new CompassControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto }, ControlPosition.BottomLeft),
                    new StyleControl(new StyleControlOptions { Style = ControlStyle.Auto, MapStyles = MapStyle.All() }, ControlPosition.BottomRight)
                }"
          StyleOptions='new StyleOptions { ShowLogo = false, Language = "en-US" }'
          EventActivationFlags="MapEventActivationFlags
                .None()
                .Enable(MapEventType.Ready, MapEventType.Click, MapEventType.DragEnd, MapEventType.SourceAdded)"
          OnReady="OnMapReadyAsync"
          OnDragEnd="OnMapDragEnd"
          OnSourceAdded="OnDatasourceAdded" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen with a lot of dynamic controls like maps. The main cause is the div that map is contained in has zero height when the map loads, and thus this happens. A common scenario where I've seen this is with tabs, where and the tab with the map is hidden initially (zero size). DOM elements don't have a resize event and so monitoring a single element for change requires additional code uses additional resources. The only resize event natively in browsers is for when the whole page resizes, which would only happen in mobile when you rotate the device. Generally you will have to manually call the "resize" method on the map to force it to rerender. Here are some methods to try and address this issue:

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of Azure Maps, it looks like you are using an old version based on the "mapbox" css class name (Azure Maps moved to "maplibre" years ago).
2. If you have a tab like experience, or an experience where the map is in a hidden div and then displayed, call the maps "resize" event when making the maps div visible.
3. If the map div is visible when the map is loaded, make sure the map has some height. Using percentages or CSS calc are both good options. If using percentages, make sure the body of your HTML has height set to 100% other wise your page won't fill the screen.

Comment: I assume you have not used AzureMapControl. And that usage of"mapbox" is from that. Which means that component is out of date - correct? Will I be better off if I use the Azure Map control directly creating my own Blazor component around it? TIA.

Comment: I was the original architect of the Azure Maps Web SDK and was very involved in the creation of the MapLibre platform and Azure Maps move to it. Thee Blazor AzureMapsComponet here: https://github.com/arnaudleclerc/AzureMapsControl.Components actually says to point to version 3 of Azure Maps (the latest version). Azure Maps moved to MapLibre with version 2. That said, that component isn't created/managed by Microsoft, so I don't have all the details on it.

Comment: Again, thank you a ton. And the Azure Map system Microsoft ships is, in my opinion, really well designed. So thanks for what you created.